# voiceover issue on mac

Tags: macos, cocoa, menu, voiceover

In my project when it is launched with VoiceOver running and the user tries to use Control-Option-M to access the menu it does not work (meaning the Apple logo is not highlighted).  By quitting VoiceOver and relaunching it works fine.  I have also confirmed that (at least most) other apps do not have this problem.  Any idea on why this would happen?  I certainly never did anything intentionally to cause this behavior.  Thanks!

rc

Comment: To make sure I understand:

Comment: To make sure I understand: 1. If you first turn VoiceOver on then launch your app, you have the problem? 2. If you then turn VoiceOver off and back on, you do not have the problem? 3. If you first launch your app then turn on VoiceOver, do you have the problem? 4. I would recommend launching your app and running Accessibility Inspector on it and looking at what the AXMenuBar attribute of your AXApplication object looks like - whether you can see any anomalies in it, what children does it have etc.

Comment: I would also recommend running with the -NSAccessibilityDebugLogLevel 1 command line attribute to make sure as much as possible accessibility-related information gets logged in the console.

Comment: Thanks Boris - 1. Yes, 2. Yes, 3. No, 4. I can't find any differences between an older version of my app without the problem and the current version with the problem. Also, I have tried with -NSAccessibilityDebugLogLevel 1 and unless I'm doing something wrong (Edit Scheme > enter as argument or variable) it never prints out anything. The good news is I have found the general cause of the problem (I'm using LSUIElement 1 and setActivationPolicy:) and this must cause some issue with the standard Control-Option-M VoiceOver command I'm assuming? Or maybe the timing of when I do it? Any ideas?

Comment: Hi Rick, w.r.t. to logging - I would think the correct is to add first argument of "-NSAccessibilityDebugLogLevel" and second argument of "1" (without the quotes) so that it does exactly what intended (as opposed to adding a single argument of "-NSAccessibilityDebugLogLevel 1"). W.r.t. to timing, from quick thinking about your answers to 1, 2 and 3, it seems that there is a problem if VoiceOver queries some things during the launch of the app as opposed to querying for them after the launch, i.e. a timing issue. But no idea further (and no experience with LSUIElement and setActivationPolicy:).

Comment: Hi again Boris. I have run the logging even direct from Terminal there is nothing being logged so no help there. But the problem does come from setActivationPolicy: and where it's being used (willFinishLaunching, etc.) so I will just work in this area. Thank you very much for your time and help!